# Checkboxes that change color of objects on canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

I can't figure out how to make a checkbox fill the objects while checked. I know  I could make them be created with the colors, but not sure how to change them after the fact with a checkbox.

```
from tkinter import *

class box:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk()
        window.title("Radiobuttons and Checkbuttons")

        self.canvas = Canvas(window, width = 400, height = 100, bg = 'white')
        self.canvas.pack()

        frame = Frame(window)
        frame.pack()
        frame2 = Frame(window)
        frame2.pack()

        self.v1 = IntVar()
        self.v2 = IntVar()
        cbtFilled = Checkbutton(frame2,text= "Filled",variable = self.v2, command = self.processCheckButton).pack(side=RIGHT)
        rbRect = Radiobutton(frame2, text = "Rectangle", variable = self.v1, value = 1, command = self.processRadiobutton).pack(side=LEFT)
        rbOval = Radiobutton(frame2, text = "Oval", variable = self.v1, value = 2, command = self.processRadiobutton).pack(side = RIGHT)

    def processCheckButton(self):
        if self.v2.get() == 1:
            print("Checked")
        else:
            print("unchecked")

    def processRadiobutton(self):
        if self.v1.get() == 1:
            self.drawRectangle()
        else:
            self.drawOval()

    def drawRectangle(self):
        self.clearCanvas()
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(35, 10 ,350,90,tags = 'rect')

    def drawOval(self):
        self.clearCanvas()
        self.canvas.create_oval(50, 10, 350, 100, tags = 'oval')

    def clearCanvas(self):
        self.canvas.delete('rect','oval')



box()
```

Answer (score 0):

By assigning the shapes to variables I am able to altar them using them itemconfigure() method.

```
self.item=self.canvas.create_oval(50, 10, 350, 100, tags = 'oval')
self.item=self.canvas.create_rectangle(35, 10 ,350,90,tags = 'rect')

def processCheckButton(self):
    if self.v2.get() == 1:
        self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.item,fill='black')
    else:

        self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.item,fill='white')
```

Comment: You can only change the rectangle because both shapes were given the same variable name.

Answer (score 0):

from tkinter import *

class box:
    def **init**(self):
        window = Tk()
        window.title("Radiobuttons and Checkbuttons")
        frame = Frame(window)
        frame.pack()
        self.canvas = Canvas(frame, width = 400, height = 100, bg = 'white')
        self.canvas.pack()

```
    frame2 = Frame(window)
    frame2.pack()

    self.v1 = IntVar()
    self.v2 = IntVar()
    cbtFilled = Checkbutton(frame2,text= "Filled",variable = self.v2, command = self.processCheckButton).pack(side=RIGHT)
    rbRect = Radiobutton(frame2, text = "Rectangle", variable = self.v1, value = 1, command = self.processRadiobutton).pack(side=LEFT)
    rbOval = Radiobutton(frame2, text = "Oval", variable = self.v1, value = 2, command = self.processRadiobutton).pack(side = RIGHT)

def processCheckButton(self):
    if self.v2.get() == 1:
        self.clearCanvas()
        if self.v1.get() == 1:
            self.drawRectangle1()
        elif self.v1.get()==2:
            self.drawOval1()
       # print("Checked")

    else:
        self.processRadiobutton()
        #print("unchecked")

def processRadiobutton(self):
    if self.v1.get() == 1:
        self.drawRectangle()
    else:
        self.drawOval()

def drawRectangle(self):
    self.clearCanvas()
    self.canvas.create_rectangle(35, 10 ,350,90,tags = 'rect')

def drawOval(self):
    self.clearCanvas()
    self.canvas.create_oval(50, 10, 350, 100, tags = 'oval')

def clearCanvas(self):
    self.canvas.delete('rect','oval')

def drawRectangle1(self):
    self.clearCanvas()
    self.canvas.create_rectangle(35, 10 ,350,90,fill = 'red',tags = 'rect')

def drawOval1(self):
    self.clearCanvas()
    self.canvas.create_oval(50, 10, 350, 100, fill= 'blue',tags = 'oval')
```

box()